# Modifying NSDatePicker for automatically generated predicate row templates

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicateeditor

How can I modify the `NSDatePickerElementFlags` for the `NSDatePicker` in row templates for `NSDate` properties returned by `[NSPredicateRowEditorTemplate templatesWithAttributeKeyPaths:inEntityDescription:]`? I would like the `NSDatePicker` to show hrs:minutes as well as the date.

**Update**
I've added an answer below, gleaned from the cocoa-dev list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Peter Ammon, on cocoa-dev, and as Ben notes, the easiest way is to modify the date picker in `-templateViews` directly:

```
[[[template templateViews] objectAtIndex:2] setDatePickerElements:...]
```

According to Peter, the order of elements in `-templateViews` is guaranteed to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably grok through the `templateViews` of the returned row templates to set this property.